# How to save a pcl::Histogram to PNG or JPG file?

Tags: c++, image-processing, point-cloud-library

I'd like to save in a file the same image I get by using PCLHistogramVisualizer of PCL API.

This is the variable with the histogram I need to save at points[0].

```
pcl::PointCloud<Histogram<100> > hist;
```

I thought it could be done by using

```
pcl::io::savePNGFile(path, *hist);
```

but this is the error I get

```
warning: ‘void pcl::io::savePNGFile(const string&, const pcl::PointCloud<PointT>&) [with T = pcl::Histogram<50>, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/png_io.h:123): pcl::io::savePNGFile<typename T> (file_name, cloud) is deprecated, please use a new generic function pcl::io::savePNGFile (file_name, cloud, field_name) with "rgb" as the field name. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

/usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/png_io.h:129:9: error: ‘const struct pcl::Histogram<50>’ has no member named ‘r’

/usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/png_io.h:130:9: error: ‘const struct pcl::Histogram<50>’ has no member named ‘g’

/usr/local/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/io/png_io.h:131:9: error: ‘const struct pcl::Histogram<50>’ has no member named ‘b’
```

So I can't do this way because it doesn't have any rgb fields, but I really need to save a huge amount of histograms and I can't screenshot all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [PCL mailing list](http://www.pcl-users.org/) for that specific questions. Developers will most probably answer there.